# Convert csv.DictReader to CSV File

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I've got a csv.DictReader called reader:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile())    
for row in reader:                   
    print(row)
```

gives me the following output:

```
{'field1': '23.10', 'field2': '48.70', 'entry_id': '18', 'created_at': '2017-09-10 09:21:43 UTC'}
{'field1': '23.10', 'field2': '48.30', 'entry_id': '19', 'created_at': '2017-09-10 10:20:35 UTC'}
{'field1': '23.00', 'field2': '48.50', 'entry_id': '20', 'created_at': '2017-09-10 11:19:29 UTC'}
```

I am trying to write this DictReader element into a csv file. The delimiter should be a `\t`and the output should look like this:

```
created_at    entry_id   field1    field2
2017-09-10 09:21:43 UTC    18   23.10   48.70
2017-09-10 10:20:35 UTC    19   23.10   48.70
```

I tried the following:

```
with open(Write_File, 'w') as csv_file:                                                                 
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file,delimiter="\t", dialect="excel-tav")
    for row in reader:                                                                         
        writer.writerow(row)
```

with no result and I tried to understand the DictWriter module but I'm not getting the desired output.

Comment: Are you trying to iterate over the reader after you printed it? Check that there's anything actually happening in your write loop - if you iterated over the reader once, there's nothing left to iterate over. And next time write a [MCVE] so it's easier for others to verify what your code does.

Comment: I actually tried to iterate of the reader after I printed it which I now know dos not work :-) This added to my confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use a `csv.DictWriter`.

```
with open('output_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['created_at', 'entry_id', 'field1', 'field2']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I got close to what you proposed but got the `writer=csv.DictWriter(csv_file...`part wrong... thanks